# sqlalchemy integrity error, unique constraint failed owner.owner_id

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am in the process of bulk adding objects to my database on the condition that it
a) doesn't already exist in my database
b) isn't already in the process of being created (because the data i'm working with could have duplicate results given to me)

Previously, to handle step b, I was storing the "to-be-created" objects in a list, and iterating through it to check if there was a matching object, but I stumbled upon sets and figured that I could just run the `.add` method on the set and know that the collection was being deduped for me.

I'm testing with a fresh database, so I know my issue exists in the process of step b.

My code looks something like

```
new_owners = set()

for item in items:
    owner = Owner.find_owner_by_id(item['owner']['id'])

    if owner is None:
        owner = Owner(owner_id=item['owner']['id'], display_name=item['owner']['display_name'])
        new_owners.add(owner)

# print to check deduped set of owners
for owner in new_owners:
    print(f'{owner.display_name} | {owner.owner_id}')

db.session.add_all(new_owners)
db.session.commit()
```

Owner.py

```
@dataclass()
class Owner(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'owner'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner_id = Column(String(40), unique=True)
    display_name = Column(String(128), nullable=False)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.owner_id == other.owner_id

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.owner_id)
```

I'm not sure what I am missing at this point, because my `print` check before adding the objects to the database session doesn't show any duplicate objects, but somehow I still get this unique constraint error.

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO owner (owner_id, display_name) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('yle42kxojqswhkwj77bb34g7x', 'RealBrhaka')]
```

Which would only happen if this object was in the given data more than once, but I would expect the set to handle deduping this